# CollectionView. const number of images on screen. Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have collection view with images. I achived const number(5) of images to view with relative layout. On my phone it looks fine.
[image]
But on other phone with different size of screen it has more images, than i need.
[image]
How to make const number of images on all screens?

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="44"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="44"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="clv" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesArray}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsAlignment="Start" SnapPointsType="Mandatory" ItemSpacing="0"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}"
                           RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.035, Constant=0}"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: its been a while since worked with xamarin.forms but if i recall correctly you should have a onscrolled event, which you can bind to a command which changes your `ImagesArray` values to have the correct ones inside. Its not clean but it should do the trick

Comment: This link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list) may help you.

Comment: When the collection has more than 5, should it scroll?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, yes, it should

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT sorry, but i saw this page before and have not found info how to do that. can you pls give me more info?

Comment: I looked at that page also. It doesn't have a solution for this. The problem is that all the built-in options (that support scrolling) assume that you want to space items with a fixed spacing. This means you'll have to *calculate* the spacing based on the available width. Tomorrow I'll see if I can find code to adapt for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CASE A: No scrolling - all items fit.**

An easy way to evenly space items is using [`VerticalGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid):

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center"
      RowDefinitions="44" ColumnDefinitions="44,*,44">
    <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="clv" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesArray}" 
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 5" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto,*">
                    <BoxView Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="40" Color="Blue" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

"VerticalGrid, 5" means that there are 5 items in each row.
These items will be evenly spaced across the width of the CollectionView.

NOTE: `ColumnSpacing="0"` in the outer grid, to maximize the space available to the middle column (the collection view).

In the ItemTemplate, I used a 3-column Grid to center the BoxView. That was needed because BoxView wants to fill the whole width of the grid cell. Might not need this for other elements - instead try HorizontalOptions=Center or HorizontalTextAlignment=Center (for Label).

---

**CASE B: Horizontal scrolling - known item and border widths.**

`EvenlySpaceItemsScrolling.xaml`:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center"
          RowDefinitions="44" ColumnDefinitions="44,*,44">
        <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="clv" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesArray}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout x:Name="MyItemsLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <BoxView WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Color="Blue" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

`EvenlySpaceItemsScrolling.xaml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestBugs
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class EvenlySpaceItemsScrolling : ContentPage
    {
        const int NItemsToShow = 5;
        const int ItemWidth = 30;

        public EvenlySpaceItemsScrolling()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            // If the amount of space to left and right of scrolling area is known,
            // we can handle it before the page is laid out.
            // See xaml: the width of left column is 44, right column is 44.
            const int SubtractThisWidth = 44 + 44;
            int collectionWidth = (int)ScreenLogicalWidth() - SubtractThisWidth;
            SetSpacingAndMargin(NItemsToShow, ItemWidth, collectionWidth);
        }


        private void SetSpacingAndMargin(int nItemsToShow, int itemWidth, int collectionWidth)
        {
            int widthPerItem = collectionWidth / nItemsToShow;
            int spacing = Math.Max(0, widthPerItem - itemWidth);
            int leftMargin = spacing / 2;

            this.MyItemsLayout.ItemSpacing = spacing;
            this.clv.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin, 0, 0, 0);

            // --- Manually test values that work well at a specific screen width. ---
            //this.MyItemsLayout.ItemSpacing = 30;
            //this.clv.Margin = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        public static double ScreenLogicalWidth()
        {
            return DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
        }

        // For demo, this is only used to get a count of items.
        // Replace with your actual source.
        public ObservableCollection<Model> ImagesArray { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model> {
            new Model(),
            new Model(),
            new Model(),
            new Model(),
            new Model(),
        };
    }
}
```

---

**CASE C: Horizontal scrolling - measure collection width.**

`EvenlySpaceItemsScrolling.xaml` - same as in CASE B.

`EvenlySpaceItemsScrolling.xaml.cs` - see CASE B, but REMOVE code in `OnAppearing`, and ADD this:

```
    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);

        // Dynamically calculate based on collection width.
        int collectionWidth = (int)this.clv.Width;
        SetSpacingAndMargin(NItemsToShow, ItemWidth, collectionWidth);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but i really need horizontal orientation of layout, because number of items in my collection not static, it may vary from 6 to 12.

Comment: Added code to calculate spacing.

Comment: Sorry for long reply. I tested your example. it has one incorrect moment. If I change screen orientation to "landscape" all going fine, item spacing calculate correclty. But if I change orientation back, item spacing become to zero. Can you help with this? Im using case "C", because in my project I can't use Xamarin.Essentials for getting screen size